# share selected image when user clicks on tweet/facebook button

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, twitter

I've got a feature that allows users to select an image from hundreds of images (artwork submitted by other users, 'creators') that have been dynamically loaded (different images are loaded on page for different users).

When a user clicks on an image: an input box, 'tweet' and 'facebook share' icon fade in. I'm trying to find a way that allows the user to share his/her selected image with their input through whichever social media icon they click like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xV0k8.png  [twitter example]

Any suggestions as to how I could do this?

**P.S.**
I'm aware of Twitter Cards but it's not exactly the same thing because I've got to specify each image which is obviously quite inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend having a look at [AddThis.com](http://www.addthis.com/) as this will let you post to various social networking websites and has a JavaScript API to let you achieve what you want.